# Deleting 'models.py' from Django app

Tags: python, django, theory

In a project, I'm implementing using `Django` framework, I have two applications:

1. Application responsible for REST API, containing production `models.py` file.
2. Application responsible for Web client, that uses REST API's models.

Both of them contain vast static files and hierarchy of additional source code, that is why it came to my mind to split this responsibilities into two apps, rather than different `views.py` and `urls.py` files inside of one application.

Because application responsible for Web relies entirely on REST API's models is it a good practice to delete `models.py` file from this application entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The file is only generated for your convenience. If you don't need it, there's no reason to keep it. No part of Django relies on it being present.